# How does glibc's write work?

Tags: c, unix, glibc

I tried to compile a simple program that called `write` with `-nostdlib`, but I got the error:

```
/path/to/file:3: undefined reference to `write'
```

I thought `write` was a Unix thing and was always there, but apparently not, turns out libc has `write` function. I found the source code:

```
/* Write NBYTES of BUF to FD.  Return the number written, or -1.  */
ssize_t
__libc_write (int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
    if (nbytes == 0)
        return 0;
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        __set_errno (EBADF);
        return -1;
    }
    if (buf == NULL)
    {
        __set_errno (EINVAL);
        return -1;
    }

    __set_errno (ENOSYS);
    return -1;
}
libc_hidden_def (__libc_write)
stub_warning (write)

weak_alias (__libc_write, __write)
libc_hidden_weak (__write)
weak_alias (__libc_write, write)
```

All this seems to be doing is setting `errno`. How does `__libc_write` write to a file descriptor?

Comment: Hmm, `stub_warning` lets me think that this source code is only a *stub* function... Where have you found it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have some misconceptions about `C` and `unix`.

> I thought `write` was a Unix thing

Definitely, `write` is a [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) which is a part of the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard. `POSIX` is a standard that is compatible with `unix` (a very old operating system).

This means that the *syscall* called `write` exists in any unix or POSIX-compliant (like Linux) operating system. However, if you don't have a an implementation of the C standard library (like glibc in Linux or bionic in Android) - how are you going to make a syscall (i.e. ask the kernel of the OS to do something)? Syscalls are architecture dependent (SPARC, Intel, ARM, PowerPC etc will have different implementations) - and are implemented by the C standard library. If you don't have one (e.g when you complie with `-nostdlib` you specifically ask not to have a C standard library) - you can't call `write`, the function doesn't exist. You can, however, implement it yourself using assembly.

The code you provided is for `__libc_write`, which is not the same as `write`. There's some voodoo that's going on between `glibc` and `gcc` here, something that has to do with stubs and I don't completely understand it.

The trivial implementation is something like this:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    return __set_errno(syscall(__NR_write, fd, buf, count));
}
```

(In `bionic`, Android's libc implementation, you can see the sources here https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/34924443/ - see that it is implemented in assembly)

The `syscall` function is implemented in assembly in `glibc` (and anywhere else): http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S (for x86_64)

However, if you must really know what's happening in `glibc` when you call `write` - it's a bit complicated. As far as I understood it, it calls `_IO_new_file_write` (implemented [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/libio/fileops.c#1255)). `_IO_new_file_write` uses the `write_not_cancel` macro defined [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h#73) which is [a macro for](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h#46) `INLINE_SYSCALL (write, 3, fd, buf, len)`, which is [the implementation](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h#194) for calling a syscall and setting errno.

Comment: "As far as I understood it, it calls _IO_new_file_write" -- you understand incorrectly, and you mixed up `write` and `fwrite`.  That part of your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: @MarkSegal [`write` is implemented by the (linux) kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/96d4f267e40f9509e8a66e2b39e8b95655617693/fs/read_write.c#L607).