# Implement my own syscalls

Tags: c, system, glibc, libc, low-level

Follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42633927/7656486) question. I'm writing my own (very basic) standard library (compiling with the `-nostdlib` gcc option). It seems that the base of almost everything is `write`, `read`, `creat`, `open`, `close`, etc.

It's my understanding that glibc simply uses stubs, `SYSCALL_INTERNAL` macros, etc. to provide those functions. I'm not using glibc and I don't want to get very complicated.

**My question.** How can I call Unix low-level functions such as `write` and `read` without glibc?

Comment: All Linux system calls are implemented via `syscall()`. You may either use it directly or look into its source code. Somewhat helpful question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149621/where-can-i-find-system-call-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make system calls directly from assembly language, for example, for Linux x86_64:

`main.c`:

```
long mywrite(int, const void *, unsigned long);

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    mywrite(1, buffer, 14);
    return 0;
}
```

`write.S`:

```
.global mywrite

.text

mywrite:
        push    %rbp
        mov     %rsp, %rbp
        mov     $1, %rax
        syscall
        leave
        ret
```

with output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/syscall$ gcc -o sc main.c write.S
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/syscall$ ./sc
Hello, world!
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/syscall$
```

Obviously this implementation doesn't set `errno` or anything like that, but that's unrelated to actually making the system calls. It'll be easier to implement a single `syscall()` function in assembly, and then have regular C functions to call it.